# Reading Data from COM Port with pyserial, but empty output

Tags: pyserial

i want to read datas from temperature meassurement. The device is connected via USB to PC.
The code shown below just deliver this output:

```
Serial port is open
b''
b''
b''
b''
```

Does somebody have anye help for me, I already looked up all familiar problems and their solutions, but none of them could help me:/

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(port='COM10', baudrate = 9600, bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,timeout=2)
try:
    ser.isOpen()
    print("Serial port is open")
except:
    print("ERROR")
    exit()

if(ser.isOpen()):
    try: 
        while( True ) :
            print(ser.read())
    except:
        print("error")
else:
    print("Cannot open serial port")
```

Comment: Add the temperature measurement instrument specifications and communication protocol information. Without them, effective answers and advice are difficult.

Comment: I dont have any instrument specifications, the name is Heater Controller HC 3500 from Tectra

Comment: If you have any programs that are already running, run them and check them out, or just try communicating with interactive terminal software?

Comment: You cannot just open the port, read data and pray for it to get what you want. You most likely have to send a command first and it will respond with the temperature. I don't see much info freely available, see [here](https://www.tango-controls.org/developers/dsc/ds/398/#dsc-Tectra3500-class-tab). Try to get a manual from the manufacturer.

Comment: I have an programm with Labview which is working fine. The device is sending data without any request